# Is there a way (in Firefox) for a user to explicitly open a link in a modal popup?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

When I'm reading dense information, often I want to follow links in the text by having them "pop up" over the underlying page in a modal way -- i.e. so that you can't lose context so easily if you switch windows, etc. -- when the modal closes, I'm back to the page that invoked it.

Firefox, like all browsers, allows you to "open link in new window" or "open link in new tab".  What I want at these times is "open link in popup", intentionally suppressing the ability to focus the underlying page.

I've tried looking for an add-in which does this, with no luck.  Anyone have any suggestions on how I can implement a modal popup like this?

Comment: this makes no sense, `open link in new windows` is basically open link in new pop up.

Comment: what does `intentionally suppressing the ability to focus the underlying page.` this mean exactly?

Comment: A "modal popup" is a software engineering concept: it means that the new window takes away it's parent's ability to receive mouse and keyboard focus.   This is a very common design idiom for web and native applications.   Not quite sure why someone would downrate simply because they're not familiar enough with computers to understand the term, but that's what it means.

Comment: @Sickest A "Modal" window means it's a child window that suspends interaction with the parent window that spawned it until the child window is closed.

Comment: @Sickest: not true.  "Open link in new window" is not the same behavior -- the underlying window is still accessible if you click on it.  If you have many windows open and tab around, etc., it is easy to get lost in the sea of open windows.  Modal popups prevent some of that confusion, at the price of "freedom".  But that's a freedom I'm trying to end in these cases.

Comment: @StableDog Not sure why the downvote - but the problem with your question as-is is that asking for an add-on that does "X" is a software request, which are considered off-topic.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Comment: @techie007, yep and i don't think the software even exists to do so.

Comment: @techie007:  I'm not sure where to post the question, then.  If not Superuser, then where?  The forum for Firefox addins is not particularly lively.  Anyway, in my experience with StackExchange forums, often some of the highest-rated questions are closed as "off topic".  I just chalk that up to the somewhat conservative mindset of the many moderators.

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SE sites in general are just not the place to ask for product recommendations (exception: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), they're better suited for a forum instead of a Q&A site.  I'd suggest editing your question and rewriting it to be about requesting a solution to popup a web page modally, instead of looking for a piece of software that does it.  Ensure you include what you've tried already, and where you're getting stuck implementing a solution that does it.

Comment: Yeah, ok.  I can do that.

Comment: The edit works for me -- retracted my close vote. :)